# coding out text issues

Tags: html, css

Hello im looking to code out part of the code to show on the page, here is what i want;

```
<input type="radio" id="q2a4" name="q4">
                Tags for external resources like images, e.g., <img>
            </label>
```

i want the  element to show as part of the label and the other label text, here is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
   <header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <h3>HTML/CSS QUIZ</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#HTML">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#CSS">CSS</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</header> 
  <body>
        <h1>HTML</h1>
        <form method="post">
          <section class="HTML" id="HTML">
            <fieldset class="q1">
            <legend class="question">
               Q1 What does HTML stand for, and what is its primary purpose?
            </legend> 
               <ul>
          <li>
                <label for="q1a1">
                <input type="radio" id="q1a1" name="q1" value="true">
                Hypertext Markup Language - To define the structure of web content
            </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="q1a2">
                    <input type="radio" id="q1a2" name="q1" value="false">
                    Hyper Transfer Text Language - To create dynamic web pages
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <label for="q1a3">
                <input type="radio" id="q1a3" name="q1" value="false">
                Hyperlink and Text Manipulation Language - To style web pages
             </label>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <label for="q1a4">
                    <input type="radio" id="q1a4" name="q1" value="false">
                    High-Level Text Management Language - To manage server-side scripts
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </fieldset>
            
         <fieldset class="q2">
            <legend class="question">
               Q2 What are HTML tags? Provide an example of an HTML tag.
            </legend>
       <ul>
         <li>
            <label for="q2q1">
                <input type="radio" id="q2a1" name="q2">
                Tags to format text, e.g., <format></format>
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="q2a2">
                <input type="radio" id="q2a2" name="q2">
                Tags to add JavaScript code, e.g., <script></script>
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="q2a3">
                <input type="radio" id="q2a3" name="q2">
                Tags to define elements in an HTML document, e.g., <div></div>
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="q2a4">
                <input type="radio" id="q2a4" name="q4">
                Tags for external resources like images, e.g., <img>
            </label>
         </li>
         </ul>
     </fieldset>
       <fieldset class="q3">
        <legend class="question">
          Q3  Describe the structure of an HTML document.
        </legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="q3a1">
                    <input type="radio" id="q3a1" name="q3">
                    HTML document has only a body element.
                </label>
            </li>
         <li>
            <label for="q3a2">
                <input type="radio" id="q3a2" name="q3">
                HTML document consists of a head and body section.
            </label>
         </li>

         <li>
            <label for="q3a3">
                <input type="radio" id="q3a3" name="q3">
                HTML document can only contain paragraphs.
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <label for="q3a4">
                <input type="radio" id="q3a4" name="q3">
                HTML document must have at least two body elements.
            </label>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="q4">
                 <legend class="question">
                   Q4 What is the purpose of HTML attributes? Provide an example.
                 </legend>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q4a1">
                            <input type="radio" id="q4a1" name="q4">
                            Attributes define the content of an element, e.g., <pre><p content="text"></p></pre>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q4a2">
                            <input type="radio" id="q4a2" name="q4">
                            Attributes specify the class of an element, e.g., <div class="container"></div>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                   <li>
                    <label for="q4a3">
                        <input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4a3">
                        Attributes add animations to elements, e.g., <img animate="fadeIn">
                    </label>
                   </li>
                  <label for="q4a4">
                    <input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4a4">
                    Attributes control the font size of text, e.g., <h1 size="24px"></h1>
                  </label>
                  </ul>
                </fieldset>        
        </section>
   <h1>CSS</h1>
        <section class="css" id="CSS">
           <fieldset class="q5">
            <legend class="question">
        Q1 What does CSS stand for, and what is its primary purpose?
       </legend>
       <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="q5a1">
                <input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5a1">
                Cascading Style Sheets - To define the presentation of web content
            </label>
        </li>
     <li>
        <label for="q5a2">
            <input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5a2">
            Computer Style Scripts - To create interactive web pages
        </label>
     </li>
    <li>
     <label for="q5a3">
        <input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5a3">
        Colorful Styling System - To add images to web pages
     </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="q5a4">
            <input type="radio" name="q5" id="q5a4">
            Central Style Selector - To manage server-side scripts
        </label>
    </li>
       </ul>
           </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="q6">
                <legend class="question">
                  Q2  How do you select elements using CSS selectors?
                </legend>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q6a1">
                            <input type="radio" name="q6" id="q5a1">
                            By ID only, e.g., #my-element
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q6a2">
                            <input type="radio" name="q6" id="q6a2">
                            By class only, e.g., .my-class
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <label for="q6a3">
                        <input type="radio" name="q6" id="q6a3">
                        By element type only, e.g., p
                       </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q6a4">
                            <input type="radio" name="q6" id="q6a4">
                            All of the above
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
     
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="q7">
                <legend class="question">
                   Q3 What is the "box model" in CSS? Explain its components.
                </legend>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q7a1">
                            <input type="radio" name="q7" id="q7a1">
                            The box model defines how images are displayed in a web page.
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q7a2">
                            <input type="radio" name="q7" id="q7a2">
                            The box model defines how elements are positioned in a web page.
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q7a3">
                            <input type="radio" name="q7" id="q7a3">
                            The box model defines how elements are styled and sized, including content, padding, border, and margin.
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="q7a4">
                            <input type="radio" name="q7" id="q7a4">
                            The box model defines how elements are colored and shaded.
What is a CSS pseudo-class, and provide an example of its usage.
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="q8">
                <legend class="question">
                   Q4 What is a CSS pseudo-class, and provide an example of its usage.
                </legend>
                <ul>
     <li>
                
                <label for="q8a1">
                    <input type="radio" name="q8" id="q8a1">
                    A pseudo-class selects elements with a specific class attribute, e.g., .active
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="q8a2">
                    <input type="radio" name="q8" id="q8a2">
                    A pseudo-class selects elements based on their position in the HTML structure, e.g., :first-child
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="q8a3">
                    <input type="radio" name="q8" id="q8a3">
                    A pseudo-class selects elements based on user interactions or states, e.g., :hover
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="q8a4">
                    <input type="radio" name="q8" id="q8a4">
                    A pseudo-class selects elements based on their IDs, e.g., #menu-item
                </label>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </section>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To render HTML code as text on a webpage you need to escape the angle brackets. For example, for an `<img>` tag to be rendered as text, you need to code it as `&lt;img&gt;`.

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150">
<br>
&lt;img src="https://picsum.photos/150"&gt;
```